# Adding multiple items to Shopify cart with one click

Tags: ajax, loops, shopify, cart

I have a Shopify site which, when viewing certain product I give the buyer the option of adding other related items at the same time. Each related product has it's own quantity input, with names "quantity1", "quantity2" etc.

What I would like to do is to count how many input names are on my page that contain the text "quantity", then create a loop over this quantity and add each item, via AJAX, that has a quantity greater than zero.

I am very new to this so not really sure what I'm doing, and have tried hours of looking into a solution but keep hitting a brick wall.

I have done the easy part, which is counting the number of "quantity" inputs using this code:

```
var len = $('input[id^=quantity]').length;
```

This is successful, but I am struggling on the loop within the AJAX call, I have tried lots of different code but none works. I would effectively like to do the following:

```
function addItemToCart(variant_id, qty) {
 var len = $('input[id^=quantity]').length;
  data = {"id": $('#quantity'+loopnumber).parent().attr('name'),
         "quantity": parseFloat($("#quantity"+loopnumber).val()),
         }
  jQuery.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/cart/add.js',
   data: data,
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function()
```

I understand I have not put the for loop code in here but that's because I don't know where to put it, and am hoping that someone could help me out please. The "loopnumber" text in the data fields would refer to the current iteration of the loop, so iteration 1 would look for the input name "quantity1" and look for it's respective value, post that to the AJAX cart, and on success loop over the next quantity values until it reaches the for loop limit. At which point it then redirects to the cart.

I know that I could simply do the following, without the loop, but this is wasteful in my opinion:

```
var quantity1 = parseFloat($("#quantity1").val());
var qty1 = $('#quantity1').parent().attr('name');
var quantity2 = parseFloat($("#quantity2").val());
var qty2 = $('#quantity2').parent().attr('name');
var quantity3 = parseFloat($("#quantity3").val());
var qty3 = $('#quantity3').parent().attr('name');
var quantity4 = parseFloat($("#quantity4").val());
var qty4 = $('#quantity4').parent().attr('name');
var quantity5 = parseFloat($("#quantity5").val());
var qty5 = $('#quantity5').parent().attr('name');

data = {
  "id": prodid,
  "quantity": mainquantity,
  
}
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/cart/add.js',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() { 
    
     data = {
       "id": qty1,
  "quantity": quantity1,
  
}
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/cart/add.js',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() { 
    
     data = {
       "id": qty2,
  "quantity": quantity2,
  
}
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/cart/add.js',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() { 
    
     data = {
       "id": qty3,
  "quantity": quantity3,
  
}
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/cart/add.js',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() { 
    
     data = {
       "id": qty4,
  "quantity": quantity4,
  
}
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/cart/add.js',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() { 
    
     data = {
       "id": qty5,
  "quantity": quantity5,
  
}
jQuery.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/cart/add.js',
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function() {  window.location.href = '/cart'
    ; 
  }
});
    ; 
  }
});
  }})}})}})}})};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks
Jon

Answer (score 0):

I've sorted it, I was overly complicating things. All I had to do was create an array and that negates having to create an AJAX loop which I couldn't get working. It's also MUCH quicker to add all the items to the AJAX cart in one go too.